# conditions for the existence of the inverse of spectral operator as a bounded linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space having a countable orthonormal base $[e_1, e_2, \cdots]$. Also, suppose $Ax = \sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} \alpha_n \langle x,e_n \rangle e_n $, where $[\alpha_n]$ is a real bounded sequence. Find the conditions under which $A^{-1}$ exists as a bounded linear operator

Now, first, obviously, $\alpha_n$s are the eigenvalues of $A$, and $\frac{1}{\alpha_n}$ would be the corresponding eigenvalue for $A^{-1}$. Therefore, one condition for the existence of $A^{-1}$ is that $\alpha_n \neq 0, \forall n.$ But what is the general way to approach this problem? And what about the boundedness of $A^{-1}$. I'd appreciate any help/hints. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $u_n=e_n$ (otherwise the $\alpha_n$ are not eigenvalues), you have
$$
\|A\|=\sup\{|\alpha_n|:\ n\}. 
$$
So $A^{-1}$ will be bounded if
$$
\sup\{|\alpha_n|^{-1}:\ n\}<\infty. 
$$

Comment: While it is clear that condition is necessary, I think depending on context it might be worth spelling out why the operator $A^{-1}$ defined in that way is actually inverse to $A$. As in, both $AA^{-1}$, $A^{-1}A$ are the identity on the dense subspace of finite support sequences.

Comment: Thanks. But, first, what about a guarantee on the very existence of $A^{-1}$? And second, how do we know that the norm of $A^{-1} $ is $\sup \{{| \alpha^{-1}|}\}?$  I mean, unless we assume that $A^{-1}$ exists and $ {| \alpha^{-1}|}$ s are its eigenvalues, cannot we say anything about the norm of the inverse operator. Am I missing something? Thanks again

Comment: @Neutrino: $A^{-1}$ exists (as a bounded operator) if and only if $\sup\{|\alpha_n|^{-1}:\ n\}<\infty$.

Comment: Thanks again. Now, I see. As a final remark, I think to begin the formal proof, I must show that  $A^{-1} $ can be written in the form of $\sum \beta_n <x,e_n>e_n$ (equation I). And then prove that each $\beta_n$ is the inverse of the corresponding $\alpha_n$. Is there any theorem that says any "linear operator" can be written in that general form in (eqn.i)?

Comment: No, your form implies that your operator is normal (selfadjoint if the coefficients are real). That's exactly the content of the Spectral Theorem. What happens here is that you know that $Ae_n=\alpha_ne_n$. It follows easily that $A^{-1}e_n=\alpha_n^{-1}e_n$. As the $\{e_n\}$ are an orthonormal basis, this defines the behaviour of the operator on the whole space (if it is bounded).

Comment: Perefct! Thanks so much